# Abrupt spike of crashes always on the same line

Tags: objective-c, crash, crash-reports

Since I submitted the new release of my app today, I experienced an impressive spike of crashes mostly concentrated on iPhone 7.1 devices version 8.4 that all seem to symbolicate in the same sequence: the last part found in my code is the show in the following piece of code:

```
- (void)connectionClosed {
     NSError* err;
    [[factory sharedFactory] clearMapArchivesWithError:&err];
    UIAlertView *message=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Crash report submitted", nil) message:NSLocalizedString(@"Notwithstanding the report about the recent crash of the app has been reported to the developer, if possible please provide him with more information about it for a more timely resolution; we thank you and apologize for the problem", nil) delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"Dismiss", nil), nil];
    [message show];
    self.waitForCrashReportToSend = NO;
}
```

Then it passes twice on a command I do not have in my own code:

> $ symbolicate 0x1000d8000 0x00000001001d63a4
>   -[MPVersion isEqual:] (in inArrivoHD) + 544 
>   $ symbolicate 0x1000d8000 0x00000001001d6304
>   -[MPVersion isEqual:] (in inArrivoHD) + 384

And finally crashes.
What could it be?

Comment: What 3rd party libs are you using? A quick search of Github suggests possibly mumble kit? Or perhaps you have a class called `MPVersion`?

Answer (score 0):

Strangely I could not comment the entry, here is the response:
I am using MumbleKit, with a limited wrapping from some classes of the MumbleForIOS app. Presently I removed all references to the library until an actual call is performed so to stem any problem in the normal usage of the app. Yet today I have no longer any crash reports of that type and an abrupt drop in the number of crashes now concentrated on something like:
reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_owned (@owned [Swift.AnyObject]!, @owned ObjectiveC.NSError!) -> (@unowned ()) slightly less obscure than the previous one.

Comment: And here are again the crashes on [MPVersion isEqual:]!